# How to make input type file wait for http request's response before opening file chooser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

I have a file chooser in my page.

```
<input type='file' id='xxx'>
```

On click of this input, I have to validate some other fields via HTTP request. Now what I want is my file chooser should wait till I get the response from the HTTP request. Is there any way I can achieve this.

On click, I am calling some method which validates everything but before it completes the method execution, file chooser comes up.

I tried for async/sync method call but NO success.

I am using angular 6.

Comment: It is unclear what selecting a file and how the other HTTP requests relate.... Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: that is somehow requirement that file chooser should open only after validation which is written over backend.

Comment: The display of the file chooser is controlled by the browser. The best you could do is intercept the `click` event, `preventDefault()` on the event based on a flag, do your async stuff, set the flag, then run the `click` again.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, In that case, I'll need to add some logic to get from where the click is being triggered so that I don't make multiple HTTP requests. Is there any other way doing that.

Comment: wouldn't it be wiser to place a [stepper of some sort](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) and simply limit access to the file dialog tab ?

Comment: So do not show it until it can be used.... disable it and show some sort of message "validating....."

Comment: Sounds like a bad user experience, frankly. When I click on a file input, I expect the file chooser to show up. If it doesn't, I'm going to wonder why the app is so slow. The validation should be triggered by every form element; when enough of them have been filled out that it makes sense to do the HTTP requests, trigger them. As @epascarello suggests, don't allow them to use the file input until the form is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need somethink like this.
UPDT: sorry, fixed example to work

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[validateClick]'
})
export class ValidateClickDirective {
  private _isValid: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this._isValid) {
      event.preventDefault();
      of(true) // your request to the server
        .pipe(delay(1000))
        .subscribe((isValid: boolean) => {
          this._isValid = isValid
          if (isValid) {
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.click();
          }
        })
    } else {
      this._isValid = false;
    }
  }

}
```

And use it:

```
<input type="file" validateClick>
```

Comment: Implemented in the same way but can see file chooser. :(

Comment: @ShubhamSharma make sure u write `<input type="file" validateClick>` without #